# In my React-Native application I want to scan Bluetooth Beacon when app is closed

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I want to scan Bluetooth in app kill mode. I don't need to connect the device just scan, It's working in background mode
I am using **react-native-ble-plx** plugin

I am trying to scan Bluetooth when React native application is closed

```
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      //const manager = new BleManager();
      const manager = new BleManager();
      const subscription = manager.onStateChange((state) => {
        if (state === "PoweredOn") {
          manager.startDeviceScan(
            ["0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"],
         
            { allowDuplicates: true, ScanMode: ScanMode.LowLatency },
            (error, device) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log("scaned device-error", error);
                // Handle error (scanning will be stopped automatically)
                return;
              }
              beaconAction(device);
            }
          );
          return () => {
            subscription.remove();
            manager.stopDeviceScan();
          };`
        }
      }, true);
    }, [])
  );
```

Comment: Scanning is not possible, but region monitoring of beacons is. Different API than BLE: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/determining_the_proximity_to_an_ibeacon_device.

Comment: Thank you @user18309290 now it's working. I have changed npm as per your suggestion for scan Beacon by uuid, major and minor

Comment: But not working for android

Comment: @VipulParmar can you please share how did you make it work? And which library you are using? According to your UUID I am expecting that you are using BeaconX devices and I need to create similar app. I'll be very happy to move forward thanks to you help.